Footer Not Visible in Mobile View on Modern SharePoint Communication Site
I'm currently working with a Modern SharePoint Communication Site and have encountered an issue where the footer is not visible when viewing the site on a mobile device. However, the footer appears perfectly fine when viewing the site on a desktop.
I've checked the required settings and configurations but haven't found any specific settings related to the visibility of the footer on mobile devices.
Is this behavior by design in SharePoint, or could I be missing something in the configuration? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Yes, this behavior is by design. I have found an official documentation from Microsoft where they have clearly mentioned that Footer is not available on mobile devices or apps.
Reference: SharePoint Site Footer

